# NHibernate Criteria query with Postgresql Timestamp column, .NET DateTime truncating milliseconds in query parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I have a NHibernate criteria query as follows:

```
using (var unitOfWork = this.UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
{
    const string fromstring = "2013-01-29 23:30:33.5993";
    var from = DateTime.Parse(fromstring);

    const string tostring = "2013-01-29 23:30:33.63434";
    var to = DateTime.Parse(tostring);

    var criteria = unitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<DataModel>();

    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Ge("Created", from));
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Le("Created", to));

    items = criteria.List<DataModel>();
}
```

I'm using Postgresql, here's the table mapping:

```
-- Table: data

-- DROP TABLE data;

CREATE TABLE data
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('data__sequence'::regclass),
  created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT itemsupdatelog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE data
  OWNER TO ubuntu;
```

And the NHibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Data" namespace="Data.Models">
  <class name="DataModel" table="Data" mutable="false">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">Data__Sequence</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="Created" not-null="true" type="Timestamp" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I can confirm that the data in the tables looks good (i.e. there ARE most definitely milliseconds on all the Created values, and when I query the values OUT of the db using NHibernate, the DateTime objects have the correct milliseconds).

However, when I use NHProf to examine the query, NHibernate is NOT sending the correct milliseconds in the query:

```
    SELECT this_.Id            as Id1_0_,
       this_.Created       as Created1_0_,
FROM   Data this_
WHERE  this_.Created >= '2013-01-29T23:30:33.00' /* :p1 */
       and this_.Created <= '2013-01-29T23:30:33.00' /* :p2 */
ORDER  BY this_.Created desc
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To be sure: is it issue of your observation of the NHProf (only) or even the query results are wrong? I tried to follow your issue (well with MS SQL) and it is working. The crucial part of mapping you have in place: `type="Timestamp"` ... so, issue with NHProf, or even query results are wrong?

Comment: I think NHProf was not showing the full millis in the window. After taking a look at my data it was working just fine.

Comment: Good news;) I thought so. Thanks for reponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The issue appears to be in NHProf. SQL reported by NHProf :

```
SELECT this_.Id      as Id0_0_,
   this_.Created as Created0_0_
FROM   data this_
WHERE  this_.Created >= '2013-01-29T23:30:33.00' /* :p0 */
       and this_.Created <= '2013-01-29T23:30:33.00' /* :p1 */
```

SQL reported in postgres log :

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id0_0_, this_.Created as Created0_0_ 
FROM data this_ 
WHERE this_.Created >= ((E'2013-01-29 23:30:33.599300')::timestamp) 
and this_.Created <= ((E'2013-01-29 23:30:33.634340')::timestamp)
```

To double check I inserted a row which falls between the milliseconds in the query:

```
insert into data (created) values ('2013-01-29 23:30:33.600')
```

And this row is returned.

Comment: I saw this same behavior in my tests as well. Thanks for the detailed answer!